# Flutter GestureDetector, onTap gets triggered automatically, how to?

Tags: flutter, setstate

I have a stateful widget that has a simple grid and each grid cell has a container inside it.

I would like to click on a cell / container and have its content changed.

The problem is that the GestureDetector -> onTap method gets triggered on app refresh for all cels.

In the example below, the `_changeCell` method gets triggered instantly for all cels and `onTap` doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GridWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridWidgetState createState() => new _GridWidgetState();
}

class _GridWidgetState extends State<GridWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Color cellColor = Colors.white;
    Text cellText = new Text('');

    // when a cell is tapped, change the color and text
    _changeCell(index) {
      setState(() {
        cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
        cellText = new Text('clicked');
      });
      print("Container clicked " + index.toString());
    }

    // create a 5 by 5 grid 
    return new GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      children: new List.generate(5, (index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          onTap: _changeCell(index),
          child: new Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: cellColor,
            ),
            child: new Center(
              child: cellText,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

just change `onTap: _changeCell(index)`  to `onTap: () => _changeCell(index)` . _changeCell(index) this returns **null** and you setting null to onTap and calling the same function .

**below code is for this**

[image: demo2]

[image: demo]

I played around a little bit.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new DemoScreen(),
  ));
}

class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoScreenState createState() => new _DemoScreenState();
}

class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> {
  Color cellColor = Colors.white;

  Text _getText(index) {
    Text text;
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        text = new Text('lightBlue');
        break;
      case 1:
        text = new Text('red');
        break;
      case 2:
        text = new Text('green');
        break;
      case 3:
        text = new Text('yellow');
        break;
      case 4:
        text = new Text('orange');
        break;
      default:
        text = new Text('brown');
        break;
    }

    return text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
        children: new List.generate(5, (index) {
          return new MyWidget(
            index: index,
            color: cellColor,
            text: _getText(index),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Text text;
  final int index;

  MyWidget({this.color, this.text, this.index});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => new _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Color cellColor = Colors.white;
  Text cellText = new Text('white');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cellColor = widget.color;
    cellText = widget.text;
  }

  _changeCell(index) {
    setState(() {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
          cellText = new Text('lightBlue');
          break;
        case 1:
          cellColor = Colors.red;
          cellText = new Text('red');
          break;
        case 2:
          cellColor = Colors.green;
          cellText = new Text('green');
          break;
        case 3:
          cellColor = Colors.yellow;
          cellText = new Text('yellow');
          break;
        case 4:
          cellColor = Colors.orange;
          cellText = new Text('orange');
          break;
        default:
          cellColor = Colors.brown;
          cellText = new Text('brown');
          break;
      }
    });
    print("Container clicked " + index.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _changeCell(widget.index),
      child: new Container(
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: cellColor,
        ),
        child: new Center(
          child: cellText,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I changed the way I call the `_changeCell` method.. but the color and text doesn't seem to change

Comment: I would like to change the color and text only on the cell I tap on

Comment: Help, when i call `myMethod` in the `onTap` attribute, i get an `only static members can be accessed in initializers` error

Comment: How to reset, rest of the box to default value?

Comment: @AkhilGite just set the initial index.

Answer (score 23):

There's a problem in your code at this line:

```
onTap: _changeCell(index),
```

Basically, instead of setting onTap to a method, you're calling the method directly and setting onTap to the result of that call (null). Each time the widget builds, it will call the function.

What you should be doing is this:

```
onTap: () => _changeCell(index)
```

Answer (score 6):

TLDR answer for those looking for a quick fix.

**Change:**

```
onTap: () => myMethod,
```

**To this:**

```
 onTap: (){ myMethod();},
```

Comment: also this works: 
onTap: () => myMethod.call()