# Flutter Gesture detector onTap problems

Tags: user-interface, flutter, gesturedetector

I am new to flutter and I'm trying to make tic tac toe game; i had some on ontap despite following the same concept in [Flutter GestureDetector, onTap gets triggered automatically, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049683/flutter-gesturedetector-ontap-gets-triggered-automatically-how-to?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My code to return the gridcells intially with red color and blank text

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Tic Tac Toe')),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            9,
            (int index){
              return new GridCell(
                index:index,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    text:Text(' '),
                  );
            })));
```

Then the class of the gridcell is:

```
class GridCell extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
 final Text text;
   final int index;


  GridCell({Key key, this.color,this.text,this.index}) : 
  super(key: key);

  @override
  GridCellState createState() {
    return new GridCellState();
  }
}

    class GridCellState extends State<GridCell> {
      Color cellColor=Colors.white;
      Text cellText=new Text(' ');
      String choice=' ';

      @override
         void initState() {
        super.initState();
        choice;
        cellColor=widget.color;
        cellText=widget.text;
      }
    //get text function to switch the x and o between the players
      String  _getText(){

        if (choice=='X'){
          choice='O';
        }
    else{
      choice='X';
    }
    return choice;
      }
    _changeCell(index) {
        setState(() {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(choice);
              print(_getText());
              break;
            case 1:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                        print(_getText());
              print(_getText());

              break;
            case 2:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                        print(_getText());

              break;

            case 3:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                        print(_getText());

              break;
            case 4:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                                  print(_getText());

              break;
              case 5:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                                  print(_getText());

              break;
              case 6:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                                  print(_getText());

              break;
              case 7:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                                  print(_getText());

              break;
              case 8:
              cellColor = Colors.lightBlue;
              cellText = new Text(_getText());
                  print(_getText());

              break;


          }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new GestureDetector(
         onTap:()=>_changeCell(widget.index),
         child:Container(
           height:20.0,
           color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
         ),
       );
      }
    }
```

The expected behaviour is 9 redgridcells appears and when i press one of the its text turns into X and its color turns into lightblue, the second press on another cell will have text O and color light blue the third's text is X and so on. The actual behaviour is 9 blue gridcells and when i press any of them nothing changes!

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What is the problem or the error? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.
The expected behaviour is 9 redgridcells appears and when i press one of the its text turns into X and its color turns into lightblue, the second press on another cell will have text O and color light blue the third's text is X and so on.
The actual behaviour is 9 blue gridcells and when i press any of them i have errors in the ui written in the terminal

Comment: And this is not happening? What is happening instead?

Comment: Sorry i edited the last comment and added the actual behaviour. could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `choice` is initialized to null and never really had a value before using it with `Text(choice)` or the conditional statement.

Comment: I initialised it to choice=' '; but the gridcells still appear to be initially  blue don't why, and the text is not updated after clicking on the cell

Answer (score 0):

Add **color: Colors.transparent,** to the Container child of the GestureDetector

And your widget will looks:

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new GestureDetector(
         onTap:()=>_changeCell(widget.index),
         child:Container(
           height:20.0,
           color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
         ),
       );
      }
```